# Maximum array size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating Array() in javascript with 80000 elements
Like

```
var arrRecWorkOrderNo = Array(1,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,80000);
```

But unfortunately Iam getting an error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Too many arguments in function call (only 32766 allowed)

How can I solve that?

Comment: do u know about `browser leaking memory` ??

Comment: Why not create an array with 80000 elements and use a for loop to populate index `i` with the value `i+1` for `i = 0; i < 80000; ++i`?

Comment: @Patashu—what would it iterate over, an array? :-)

Comment: @RobG You can't pre-create an array of 80000 elements all with default value in Javascript? (I am not a Javascript coder)

Comment: @Patashu—Javascript arrays are just objects, they only have elements if they are created individually. E.g. `var a = new Array(20)` creates an array with a length of 20 and no members, e.g. `'0' in a == false`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `Array`, just define it as:

```
var arrRecWorkOrderNo = [1,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,80000];
```

Javascript has a limit of 32766 (signed short) when you put it as arguments to a constructor.

Comment: Actually, this is way better than my answer, duh. Deleting my answer.

Comment: That's an [array initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) or array literal.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Array` constructor, see Ken's answer for the right usage. Array constructor has weird behavior when called with arguments.

However, if you ever need to have more than *32766* arguments in a function (There is no excuse for that, really), you do something like:

```
var a = Array.apply(null, [1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,80000];
```

`apply` function sets the first parameter as `this` objects and second parameter as `arguments`.

Note: This is just a proof of concept, no one should ever have that much parameters, just accept an array.